# using cin to change a 2d string array value

Tags: c++, arrays, 2d, cin

```
const string astrDice[6][4]
{
    {"M1" , "DM" , "AT" , "BK"},
    {"M2" , "DM" , "BK" , "BK"},
    {"M3" , "DM" , "BK" , "BK"},
    {"M4" , "BK" , "AT" , "BK"},
    {"M5" , "BK" , "AT" , "BK"},
    {"M6" , "BK" , "AT" , "BN"}
};

   cout << "Choose Side (1-6):";
       int nSideChoice = 0;
       cin >> nSideChoice;    // will -1 later for ease of use to operator
   cout << "Choose a Slot (1-4):";
       int nSlotChoice = 0;
       cin >> nSlotChoice;    // will -1 later for ease of use to operator
   cout << "Enter a New Value:";
       string strNewSlot;
       cin >> strNewSlot;

   astrDice[nSideChoice - 1][nSlotChoice - 1] = strNewSlot;
```

says "No Viable Overloaded "=" on the last line. I want to use the nSideChoice and nSlotChoice to change that selection in the array. I am still learning how to do basic code, and only know bits of C++ right now. this is just a test program I have been working on, and constantly changing as I learn new things.

Comment: maybe not make it a `const string astrDice[6][4]` , instead `string astrDice[6][4]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at this line : `const string astrDice[6][4]`

astrDice is const, you can't modify it!

The compiler should say something like `error: passing 'const string' as 'this' argument of 'something' discards qualifier`. When you see a message like this, it usually means that you have constness issues.

`No Viable Overloaded "="` is not the best error message ever. It's trying to say that std::string doesn't have a const operator=(). Well, duh.

It's important to try to understand the error messages, even if they are a bit stupid sometimes. You'll save a lot of time.

Comment: thank you. that fixed it. i did that earlier in attempt to make something else work and completely forgot about it! works now!

Answer (score 2):

Your array is `const`, meaning that you can't modify it after it's been initialized. Remove the `const` qualifier and your code should work.

Answer (score 2):

Because of the `const` qualifier here `const string astrDice[6][4]` you will be unable to edit this array. Yes you can change the element to `string astrDice[6][4]` but is that really a good solution?

Lets take a lok at this line:

```
cout << "Choose Side (1-6):";
   int nSideChoice = 0;
   cin >> nSideChoice;
```

what if the user puts a side choice of 7? Then here: `astrDice[nSideChoice][nSlotChoice] = strNewSlot;` you are going to have serious memory issues. Consider using a `std::vector` for this:

```
vector<vector<string>> astrDice =
{
    {"M1" , "DM" , "AT" , "BK"},
    {"M2" , "DM" , "BK" , "BK"},
    {"M3" , "DM" , "BK" , "BK"},
    {"M4" , "BK" , "AT" , "BK"},
    {"M5" , "BK" , "AT" , "BK"},
    {"M6" , "BK" , "AT" , "BN"}
};

   cout << "Choose Side (1-6):";
       int nSideChoice = 0;
       cin >> nSideChoice;
   cout << "Choose a Slot (1-4):";
       int nSlotChoice = 0;
       cin >> nSlotChoice;
   cout << "Enter a New Value:";
       string strNewSlot;
       cin >> strNewSlot;

   astrDice.at(nSideChoice).at(nSlotChoice) = strNewSlot;
```

This way you will be protected against out of bounds array problems.

Comment: im not sure what a vector is yet, again i am still learning. i have an if statement in the code to protect against that. ill look into that once i learn about vectors.

Comment: and using `std::vector` and `.at()` gives you Strong guarantee,
It throws [out_of_range](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stdexcept/out_of_range/) if is accessed out of bounds

Comment: @AmpMunkey when you learn about c++ stl types you will try to never use a c-style array again. They are so much better. `.at()` will throw an exception if the array bounds are violated.

Answer (score 0):

O_o
Woah ... indeed

Define constraint to write program or body function ...

-> You are asking user to enter numerical value ( signed value of architecture bit : example 32bit )
-> That's not what you are asking for your code that require ranged value between 1-6 and later 1-4
-> You compute yourself the matrix dimension of your array ( is that a matrix or a vector of vector )
---> vector of vector don't add constraint on lenght of each vector, matrix add it
---> whenever you aren't sure, use slicer , simplicity over complexity
-> key adress should be handled by map container not vector

It doesn't matter what language you are using, just be specific and handle constraint at the very beginning of coding.

Also STD::CIN is ERROR PRONE ... it's a very basic low level mechanism to read value ( peek, get, readsome and ignore will be harmfull in many way for rookiee ) where almost in 99% you want a regex control for input.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <valarray>

using namespace std;

const int IHM_MAXREAD_LOOP= 3;
const int BLCK_SIDE= 6;
int main()
{
   valarray<string> astrDice=  // deserialized matrix
            {"M1" , "DM" , "AT" , "BK"
            ,"M2" , "DM" , "BK" , "BK"
            ,"M3" , "DM" , "BK" , "BK"
            ,"M4" , "BK" , "AT" , "BK"
            ,"M5" , "BK" , "AT" , "BK"
            ,"M6" , "BK" , "AT" , "BN"
            };

    map<int,valarray<string> > astrDice;
    for(int i=0;i<BLCK_SIDE;++i) astrDice[i]=data[slice(i, BLCK_SIDE, 1)]; // adding constraint on block size , remove constraint on index

    string in1,in2, readyparse;
    smatch match;    
    regex re("[1-6] [1-4]");
    int maxtry;
    for( maxtry = IHM_MAXREAD_LOOP; !regex_match(readyparse, match, re) && maxtry>0 ; maxtry--)
    {
        cout << "Choose Side (1-6):";
        cin >> in1;
        cout << "Choose a Slot (1-4):";
        cin >> in2;
        readyparse = in1+" "+in2;
    }
    if(maxtry<=0)
    {
        cout << "Run only with 1 2 3 4 5 or 6 for Side and 1 2 3 or 4 for Slot " << std::endl;
    }else {
        cout << "Enter a New Value:";
        cin >> astrDice[atol(in1.c_str())-1][atol(in2.c_str())-1];
    }
}
```